# export binary data from postgres table to a csv and then read csv to create a dataframe using copy command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to export the model data(in bytea format stored in psql database) into a csv and then create a dataframe using pandas.

My code which I tried:

```
query = ("""SELECT  model from {} where col1 = '{}' and col2 = '{}'""").format(
        os.environ['table'], os.environ['col2'], hier)

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpFile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
            query=query, head="HEADER"
        )
        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpFile)
        tmpFile.seek(0)
        dataFrame = pd.read_csv(tmpFile)
```

It dataFrame['model'] gives data in string and not bytes-like object format.

*Update*:
 Using pd.read_sql command ;

```
dataFrame = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine, columns=['col1', 'model'])
```

Comment: Why do you want to go through CSV instead of creating the dataframe directly from SQL data?

Comment: @Błotosmętek yeah, I tried pd.read_sql, but I came to knw that pd.read_sql is slower than going through the pd.read_csv command

Comment: This sounds quite unlikely; how exactly were you using `read_sql`? Also, what use is a faster method if it doesn't produce correct result?

Comment: @Błotosmętek I have updated the quesn with the read_sql command , Can you suggest a different method apart from read_sql to create a df of binary data

Comment: @Błotosmętek https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809892/10861949 this link explains the thinking behind using read_csv method

Comment: I am still not completely convinced this is worth the effort, but, if you insist, you could probably go with your approach and fix the binary data by applying `str.encode` to the appriopriate columns in the resulting dataframe. Also be warned that PostgreSQL 9.x exports bytea encoded in hex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730729/how-to-download-postgres-bytea-column-as-file